# C - passing function with arguments into wrapper executor

Tags: c

Is there a way to build a wrapper function in C as follows:

```
void wrapper(void *func) {
  // Set up
  func([same arguments as func was passed in with]);
  // Clean up
}

void foo(int x, int y);
void bar(char *z);

wrapper(foo(1, 2));
wrapper(bar("Hello"));
```

It seems as though you have to either pass in the arugments within `wrapper` or only support one type of method header for `func`.  I've been writing a lot of Javascript... and of course this is possible in JS.

Comment: You could use a variadic function for wrapper.

Comment: @ForceBru so then I'd need some kind of branching logic inside `wrapper` to distinguish between `foo` and `bar`?

Comment: On another note, if you want a feature from Javascript you should probably write your code in Javascript...

Comment: Not sure if I agree with you there Seb.  I'd like a lot of features from Javascript/Python/etc, but given I'm writing a basic operating system, I don't think that's gonna be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the best I can think of with variadic function wwrappers:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void wrapper(void (*func)(va_list), ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, func);

    func(args);

    va_end(args);
}

void foo(int x, int y)
{
    printf("foo(%d,%d)\n", x, y);
}
void vfoo(va_list args)
{
    foo(va_arg(args, int), va_arg(args, int));
}
void bar(char *z)
{
    printf("bar(%s)\n", z);
}
void vbar(va_list args)
{
    bar(va_arg(args, char*));
}

int main()
{
    wrapper(vfoo, 1, 2);
    wrapper(vbar, "Hello, World!");
    return 0;
}
```

[Live example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b29d9c41105000a5).

Comment: Cool- I guess you don't need any logic inside wrapper.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered (ab)using the preprocessor?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define wrapper(f) /* Set up   */\
                   f;            \
                   /* Clean up */

void foo(int x, int y) {
    printf("x: %d; y: %d\n", x, y);
}

void bar(char *str) {
    printf("str: %s\n", str);
}

int main(void) {
    wrapper(foo(42, 11));
    wrapper(bar("hello world"));
}
```

To elaborate upon why I added the possibility of an ab- prefix to (ab)use, I wouldn't hesitate to use whatever is the most expressive solution to a problem, regardless of the attitude held by the general populus. However, I recognise that sometimes we have no control over the restrictions we are bound by, and policies are often put in place to heavily restrict the use of macros. Unfortunately, those bound by such silly policies won't find this post too helpful.

In a comment above I suggested that "if you want a feature from Javascript you should probably write your code in Javascript...".

Upon pondering about this overnight, I came to the conclusion that features similar to those you ask are actually doable and would be quite nice in C... so I admit, I was wrong.

The following is an example of mimicking how Javascript treats functions.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct argument;
typedef struct argument argument;
typedef void function(argument *);

struct argument {
    function *function;

    /* for foo() */
    int x;
    int y;

    /* for bar() */
    char *str;
};

void wrapper(argument *a) {
    // set up
    a->function(a);
    // clean up
}

void foo(argument *a) {
    printf("x: %d; y: %d\n", a->x, a->y);
}

void bar(argument *a) {
    printf("str: %s\n", a->str);
}

#define foo(...) wrapper(&(argument){ .function = foo, __VA_ARGS__ })
#define bar(...) wrapper(&(argument){ .function = bar, .str = "", __VA_ARGS__ })

int main(void) {
    foo(.x = 42, .y = 11);
    bar(.str = "hello world");
}
```

There are actually some really nice features coming from this style of wrapper:

- **It becomes very difficult for a down-stream programmerr to *mung the stack***, where-as it is very easy for programmers using typical variadic functions such as `printf` and `scanf` to cause subtle yet devastating bugs by passing the wrong types and/or values to those functions. This leads on to my next point:
- **Default argument values are possible** by simply modifying the `foo` and `bar` macros. As an example in the code above, the default value for the argument named `str` is set to `""` (an empty string) for `bar`.
- By introducing extra logic into `wrapper`, you can mimic partial function application (or binding properties to functions, much like you'd see in Javascript). Additionally, with a little bit of effort, mimicking continuation passing style *might* be possible by turning `wrapper` into a trampoline-style function and modifying the return value? I'll ponder more on this and provide an update tomorrow.
- Finally, down-stream users are encouraged to pair argument identifiers with argument values, which improves maintainability drastically.

There are some minor draw-backs, the most significant being that neither `foo` nor `bar` can be passed, unapplied, to another function as an argument. This would be rare for these functions specifically, as they differ greatly in signature, but for functions that are identical or even similar in signature I can understand one might want to pass them as callbacks or what-not.

The solution to that problem is to rename the macros to `default_foo` and `default_bar` or something like that...

Finally, thanks for asking such a thought-provoking question... I hope reading my answer has been as interesting for you as thinking about (and writing) it was for me.

Comment: The `#define` needs parentheses

Comment: @ringø Which `#define` are you referring to?

Comment: So the first one? I think you are mistaken. The OP explicitly wants to be able to invoke functions with different signatures inside of `wrapper`, for example: `wrapper(foo(42, 11)); wrapper(bar("hello world"));`...

Comment: I've been mistaken, indeed ;-)

Comment: @ringø That happens to the best of us. Consider it a nice ego boost that you're able to recognise and move forward from it. Most people would put up a mental blockade to defend their ego.

Comment: @sir_thursday After pondering on your requirements for a while, I came to the conclusion that I was wrong when I suggested to use Javascript (in the comments). Please see my edit; hopefully you find something nice there :)